# macro program not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, macros, pygame, keypress

I have been looking for a way to make an autoclicker, since I haven't had any experience with clicking/typing in Python via a macro. I wanted the program to be able to detect when I press a button (F1) and start clicking constantly until I press the stop button (F2); unfortunately, my code won't output the `cps` variable and the `x` and `y` variable. I just need to be able to detect that it's working there to move on to my actual clicking.

Basically, I'm asking how to fix the key detection.
Python version: 3.6.5

EDIT:  i know it checks for 1 and 2, the f1 was opening a python help screen when pressed- so for now im just doing 1 and 2

```
import random, pygame, pyautogui, time 
loop = 1
on = 0
pygame.init()
while(loop == 1):
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if(key[pygame.K_1]):
        on = 1
    elif(key [pygame.K_2]):
        on = 0
    if(on == 1):
        x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        cps = random.randint(10,20)
        print(cps, x,y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a user event and call [`pygame.time.set_timer`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) with this event as the first argument and pygame will start adding the event to the queue after the specified time interval.

```
import random
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
CLICK_EVENT = pg.USEREVENT + 1

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_1:
                pg.time.set_timer(CLICK_EVENT, 1000)  # Start the timer.
            elif event.key == pg.K_2:
                pg.time.set_timer(CLICK_EVENT, 0)  # Stop the timer.
        elif event.type == CLICK_EVENT:
            print(random.randint(10, 20), pg.mouse.get_pos())

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks! i'm grateful you gave a quick response that made sens

Answer (score 1):

Your code currently checks for the `1` and `2` number keys.

You want `K_F1` and `K_F2`, not `K_1` and `K_2`, for the function keys.

Comment: i know. the F2 and F1 were opening python help tools, so for now im tring to just get 1 or 2